# Zero4u usb hub on raspberry pi Zero W does not recognize whatever USB device I connect to it

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, otg

I am writing to tell how I managed to solve my USB hub problems related to raspberry pi zero W, but I would still want a feedback and related help on this.

The issue was, I could not get anything recognized on the usb port of the raspberry using my OTG cable:

[image]

(without using usb hub). Some could argue that the issue might be that the OTG I made is a custom cable and it was its own fault.

But even when I connected the Usb hub ([Zero4u](http://www.uugear.com/product/zero4u/)), it recognized the usb hub, but nothing that I connected to it (a mouse, usb stick, keyboard), nothing.

[image]

Here I even power the USB hub with a separate power:

[image]

But it could only recognize the usb hub, not the USB stick you see on the picture, or anything else I connected to it. Using

```
lsusb
```

I could only get the usb hub info.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I managed to overcome this by using this Chinese (I bought that from Aliexpress) adapter for micro-SDs: (but only to use the SD card)

[image]

I still cannot use any mouse or keyboard (I control the Zero from VNC and SSH) But at least I know Its the Hub's fault.